# Is there a way to bin categorical data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe where one column is U.S. states. I'd like to create a new column and bin the states according to region, i.e., South, Southwest, etc. It looks like pd.cut is only used for continuous variables, so binning that way doesn't seem like an option. Is there a good way to create a column that's conditional on categorical data in another column?

Comment: One way is to use conditionals like df[‘south’] = df[‘state’].isin(SOUTHERN_STATES) where SOUTHERN_STATES is a list of southern state names

Comment: Building on above you can create a function that bins the states and use series.apply to create a new column. df[‘region’] = df[‘state’].apply(func) where func returns the region name according to the state name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def label_states (row):
    if row['state'] in ['Maine', 'New Hampshire', 'Vermont', 'Massachusetts', 'Rhode Island', 'Connecticut', 'New York', 'Pennsylvania', 'New Jersey']:
        return 'north-east'
    if row['state'] in ['Wisconsin', 'Michigan', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Ohio', 'North Dakota', 'South Dakota', 'Nebraska', 'Kansas', 'Minnesota', 'Iowa', 'Missouri']:
        return 'midwest'
    if row['state'] in ['Delaware', 'Maryland', 'District of Columbia', 'Virginia', 'West Virginia', 'North Carolina', 'South Carolina', 'Georgia', 'Florida', 'Kentucky', 'Tennessee', 'Mississippi', 'Alabama', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas', 'Arkansas', 'Louisiana']:
        return 'south'
    return 'etc'

df = pd.DataFrame([{'state':"Illinois", 'data':"aaa"}, {'state':"Rhode Island",'data':"aba"}, {'state':"Georgia",'data':"aba"}, {'state':"Iowa",'data':"aba"}, {'state':"Connecticut",'data':"bbb"}, {'state':"Ohio",'data':"bbb"}])

df['label'] = df.apply(lambda row: label_states(row), axis=1)

df
```

[image: The output:]

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your *df* contains:

- *State* - US state code.
- other columns, for the test (see below) I included only *State Name*.

Of course it can contain more columns and more than one row for each state.

To add region names (a new column), define *regions* DataFrame,
containing columns:

- *State* - US state code.
- *Region* - Region name.

Then merge these DataFrames and save the result back under *df*:

```
df = df.merge(regions, on='State')
```

A part of the result is:

```
        State Name State              Region
0          Alabama    AL           Southeast
1          Arizona    AZ           Southwest
2         Arkansas    AR               South
3       California    CA                West
4         Colorado    CO           Southwest
5      Connecticut    CT           Northeast
6         Delaware    DE           Northeast
7          Florida    FL           Southeast
8          Georgia    GA           Southeast
9            Idaho    ID           Northwest
10        Illinois    IL             Central
11         Indiana    IN             Central
12            Iowa    IA  East North Central
13          Kansas    KS               South
14        Kentucky    KY             Central
15       Louisiana    LA               South
```

Of course, there are numerous variants of how to assign US states to regions,
so if you want to use other variant, define *regions* DataFrame according
to your classification.